# Http Bindings in .Net Core consuming a Library Project with wcf reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, .net-core, wcf-binding

My .net core 3.1 project references a class library project built in .Net Framework 3.5.
The library project has a wcf service reference with bindings defined in app.config.

In dotnet framework we usually provide the http bindings in the consuming project.

When I try to manually add service bindings in app.config in dotnet core (consuming project) I get this error - "*Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel*"

Is there any way in which I can provide http bindings in the project which references the library project.

**Update 1**

This is my app.config in dotnet core project -

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="username" value="usr"/>
        <add key="password" value="pass"/>
        <add key="logPath" value="c:\test\api_log.txt"/>    
    </appSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ListManagementSoap">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="ListManagementSoap1" />
                <binding name="ContactManagementSoap">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="ContactManagementSoap1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://ws.caigners.com/listmanagement.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ListManagementSoap"
                contract="ListManagementAPI.ListManagementSoap" name="ListManagementSoap" />
            <endpoint address="https://ws.caigners.com/contactmanagement.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ContactManagementSoap"
                contract="ContactManagementAPI.ContactManagementSoap" name="ContactManagementSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, .net core does not support the creation of WCF services, but you can create WCF clients in .net core to call WCF services. Although you can call WCF services in .net core, it is subject to some restrictions. The WCF client in .net core only supports four bindings: BasicHttpBinding, CustomBinding, NetHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding, and there are not many security features in .net Core.

[image]

If you want to recognize system.serviceModel, you need to install System.ServiceModel.Http. For more information about it, you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/tree/main/release-notes).

Comment: I tried adding "System.ServiceModel.Http" nuget package. I still get "Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel" error. I've updated the OP with my app.config.

Comment: This may be because System.ServiceModel.Http does not contain the system.serviceModel node. I suggest you use the .net framework.

Comment: Yes I had to go around it and rewrite the dotnet framework 3.5 (WCF consuming project) to core 3.1. It was a long and tedious but did the job. Thanks :)